# Using regex in python to parse JSON fields

Tags: python, regex, json, django

I am writing a test function for seeing if an auto-complete field has all the results from the database.

The auto-complete field returns a list from the database by creating a JSON list of items.

I want to know how to write the correct regex expression to find all the items I need.

tests.py:

```
from django.test import TestCase
import unittest
import re
import requests

class TestBuilds(unittest.TestCase):

def test_autoField_mobo(self):
        '''
        Test if all motherboards from database appear in autocomplete
        '''
        mobos_db = moboListing.objects.values_list('moboList', flat = True)
        r = requests.get('localhost:8000/builds/autocomplete/ajax_lookup/moboListing?term=+') 
# When user enters a space, request to server returns JSON format of motherboards at this url
        num_mobos_db = len(mobos_db) # number of motherbaords in db
        autocomplete = re.findall(r'u'value': u'(.*?)', str(r.json()) , re.DOTALL)
        flag = False
        error = """Check that all motherboards from DB really appears"""
        for i in range(0, num_mobos_db):
        if mobos_db[i] in autocomplete:
            flag = True
        else:
            flag = False
        self.assertTrue(flag, error)
```

My problem is how to write the correct regex expression for the JSON string which looks like this:

```
>>> str(r.json())

"[{u'pk': u'1', u'value': u' ASUS Motherboard '}, {u'pk': u'2', u'value': u' MSI Motherboard '}]"
```

I want all the Motherboard names to be collected from the `u'value': u' '` so that I can check if they match with the database, or if there is a way to count the number of JSON items, I can just compare that with the number of motherboards in my database.

Comment: Why are you converting your list of dicts into a string so you can parse it?  Why not just pull the elements straight from the dicts and validate those?

Comment: You cannot parse JSON with regular expressions, unless you assume for example that there is a fixed maximum nesting of objects. But even in that case it will be very difficult. Why don't you just use `json.loads()` and operate on dictionaries and lists?

Comment: Ok thanks, I am goiing to read up on `json.loads()` and report back here

Comment: I may not be understanding your question but core functions like json.dumps, serialize and model.objects.all() dont need to be tested

Comment: @skzryzg that's what I thought, I'm not sure what to be testing so I thought might as well test the auto-complete feature. My professor wants us to test.

Comment: @freakish How can I use json.loads() to get the JSON from the url and count the number of `pk`?

Comment: @achabacha322 i was confused about what to test at first, too.  I found this very helpful when I was starting out: http://toastdriven.com/blog/2011/apr/10/guide-to-testing-in-django/